# Getting a PAMediaConversionServiceErrorDomain error 2 when importing an image using a PHPickerViewController

Tags: ios, phpickerviewcontroller

I got this message when trying to import an image using a PHPickerViewController:

> 2022-10-29 12:52:17.775185+0200 screenfreeze[38500:5423936] [claims] 2AA2E9DE-9603-4723-B04C-35F09BB99667 grantAccessClaim reply is an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4101 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000f20330 {Error Domain=PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHAssetExportRequestErrorDomain error 0.), NSUnderlyingError=0x600000f20300 {Error Domain=PAMediaConversionServiceErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (PAMediaConversionServiceErrorDomain error 2.)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (PAMediaConversionServiceErrorDomain error 2.)}}}}}

What causes this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 15):

I got this error when I tried to select this flower picture from the iOS simulator:

[image: flower picture]

The other sample pictures and images I imported have no such issue.

I noticed that only that sample image is HDR. I think the issue is that the flower image is somehow corrupted, because it works with HDR images I took.

Comment: This answer in no way grows out of the info in the question. In any case, that the first Simulator image is problematic is well known (even to Apple). See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666338

Comment: @matt Still, it can be useful, I didn't know that the flower image had issues and this answer would've saved me time

Comment: I can't believe this! I have been using iOS simulators for years and never had this issue with the first photo. This is totally unreal and pathetic on Apple's part. Thank god for this comment.

Answer (score 8):

It's a known issue that the red flower image can't be selected using the simulator (63426347).

The issue only affects the simulator environment so it should work on actual hardwares. If you want to continue using the simulator to test, you can select other images instead.

See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699155 for more information.